# How should be email data structured to force Gmail to categorize as Update?

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have some handmade web page, where client has to verify an email address after registration. When I send mail through the system, it delivers correctly, but Gmail doesn't categorize it as Update (tab/category) like on other emails do.

So I thought maybe there is some standard of structured data or some meta tags which will help Gmail to understand that this mail should be categorized as update.

Any considerations will be appreciated.